# Tuple argument with correct return type for a function

Tags: typescript

How to return the correct type associated function argument as a tuple? I would like a function to return its value based on its argument's tuple type.

The example below is a `get` function, but I would like to get it working with `getAll` function and argument as a tuple.

```
type PathImpl<T, Key extends keyof T> =
  Key extends string
  ? T[Key] extends Record<string, any>
    ? | `${Key}.${PathImpl<T[Key], Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof any[]>> & string}`
      | `${Key}.${Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof any[]> & string}`
    : never
  : never;

type PathImpl2<T> = PathImpl<T, keyof T> | keyof T;

type Path<T> = PathImpl2<T> extends string | keyof T ? PathImpl2<T> : keyof T;

type PathValue<T, P extends Path<T>> =
  P extends `${infer Key}.${infer Rest}`
  ? Key extends keyof T
    ? Rest extends Path<T[Key]>
      ? PathValue<T[Key], Rest>
      : never
    : never
  : P extends keyof T
    ? T[P]
    : never;

declare function get<T, P extends Path<T>>(obj: T, path: P): PathValue<T, P>;

const object = {
  firstName: "test",
  lastName: "test1"
} as const;

get(object, "firstName");

declare function getAll<T, P extends Path<T>>(obj: T, args: P[]): PathValue<T, P>;

const data = getAll(object, ['firstName', 'lastName'])
// how to produce the type: ['test', 'test1']
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20210107#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgSQLZgDYB4AqAaKAaQhCggA9gIA7AEwGcoBrEgewDMocA+KAXgBQUIiTKUaDKPWAAnAJbUA5kKgB+LgG1iIALpiqdRgCUIAY1YzaWafKUE41ENxXD1AHygADACQBvbQC+AHR+8EhomLhaJDoEAKLkphgArrQQWCwgHJrascxsnA4gGjrcvABkUrIKigGeLsJQHj7+JMF+CUmp6ZnZONG6BL2FjiUVVba19Y1QAFxQ1BAAbhAyKvOLKzIA3AICoJCwCCjoGABMuLx8R+GnuEMFXLwew1y7++DQYYiX-DcnmAuPH0EkYNhqTXyWU4ODU-wi51+81eOHeBy+xwAanAUul8LAQYZ-pcrioYITJC0FOxViIQO1fNTaSZpHUVOptBTGCiGuoWcAucT+rlnDNXP9sbiorkCPzRWKNstVg1FVt1gSKAZJDyZup+jAdCqFkqdns0kk4DJoOxktRTMA5KxqFBFBBgPcNeIid8SQAKVgAIwAVvN8WBjvMYABKSNYnHJPEEGDcd7majSKCBoNmAXXXwqdhyGTSABycFQEHmACIqNIq3gVBg4KXy5WoDWIHWBAEoM2oGnpO9XcB-cGcwQq4Xi8AyxWq1H3uam1aoDa7Q6nS63QBBDDYfHkzWgoVlUchrj2GSKeiRkoxiXxxOwFN7AcC2gIOB-Ye7jBn8dQBoADkU4thWQEEEBTZgRAQE6FGAgAPSIVAiCsAA7lAwCsFAYAyKwtDJKY0BICRnzzMBtbABBUBAVRcFAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to map the tuple passed in. You also have to change the type parameter to capture the tuple type.

```
type MapAllPaths<T, P extends Path<T>[]> = {} & {
  [K in keyof P ]: PathValue<T, P[K] & Path<T>>
}

declare function getAll<T, P extends [Path<T>] | Path<T>[]>(obj: T, args: P): MapAllPaths<T, P>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20210107#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgSQLZgDYB4AqAaKAaQhCggA9gIA7AEwGcoBrEgewDMocA+KAXgBQUIiTKUaDKPWAAnAJbUA5kKgB+LgG1iIALpiqdRgCUIAY1YzaWafKUE41ENxXD1AHygADACQBvbQC+AHR+8EhomLhaJDoEAKLkphgArrQQWCwgHJrascxsnA4gGjrcvABkUrIKigGeLsJQHj7+JMF+CUmp6ZnZONG6BL2FjiUVVba19Y1QAFxQ1BAAbhAyKvOLKzIA3AICoJCwCCjoGABMuLx8R+GnuEMFXLwew1y7++DQYYiX-DcnmAuPH0EkYNhqTXyWU4ODU-wi51+81eOHeBy+xwAanAUul8LAQYZ-pcrioYITJC0FOxViIQO1fNTaSZpHUVOptBTGCiGuoWcAucT+rlnDNXP9sbiorkCPzRWKNstVg1FVt1gSKAZJDyZup+jAdCqFkqdnt0VAALJwMAAQQwGG+9HuGvERO+lzGf18ASglV8Ki0UAUUOy5J082+kuSeIIMC0ekq7p4zgCAjSSTgMmg7GS1FMwDkrGoUEUEGAzvJmtBQrKAApWAAjABW83xYGOEYAlBGsTjoxXuO9zNRpFBG02zALrv7hOw5DJpAA5OCoCDzABEVGk67wKgwcCXK7XUE3EG3Ah9B6gw+k71LwHrzcnBHXc4XwGXq-Xnfe6f3WagHM8wLIsSzLO1sHxStXUkDQk24PQPHgsZHxbLh7BkRR6C7eYrVte1HQHIci1HWgEDgP57wg1DnygDQAHI30PVd6IIej92YiB6J0TsBAAej4qBEFYAB3KBgFYKAwBkVhaGSUxoCQRTPnmBit2AVioHo9TuL2MjgDgIA)